# Keplergl react duplicates Layers upon adding more datasets got from supabase

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, eclipse-kepler, kepler.gl

I'm trying to visualize data from supabase onto KeplerGl map but KeplerGl keeps on duplicating layers upon adding new data to the map.
[image]

When I set `keepExistingConfig: false` it wipes all the existing layers and adds the last fetched datasets.
I kindly need some help on this task.
Here is my keplergl map

In `AddDataToMap.js` file, same as `AddPoints` and `AddMonitoringDeviceStatus` files

```js
const ADD = () => {
  const data = fetch('from/some/endpoint');
  
  const geojson = { 
    datasets: { info: {id: 'my_data'},data: processGeojson(data) }
    options: { keepExistingConfig: true },
   ... // other configs
  }
 
  useEffect(()=>{
     
     dispatch(addDataToMap(geojson))    

     });
    return null;
  }
```

In `map.js` file

```js
const Map = () => (

   <ErrorBoundary>
        <AutoSizer>
          {({ height, width }) => (
            <KeplerGl
              id="map"
              store={store}
              width={width}
              height={height}
              mapboxApiAccessToken={token}
              onHover={handleLayerHover}
              onClick={handleLayerClick}
            />
          )}
        </AutoSizer>
    </ErrorBoundary>
      <AddDataToMap />
      <AddPoints />
      <AddMonitoringDeviceStatus />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my current implementation, I was dispatching `addDataToMap` action in every component.

- The best implementation is [here](https://github.com/keplergl/kepler.gl/issues/172)

gist

```js
const Map = () => {
 const addData = async() => {
   const data_1 = await fetchData1();  
   const data_2 = await fetchData2();  
   
   if([data_1, data_2].includes(undefined)) return;

  const datasets = [
      {
         { info: { id: 'data_1' }, data: data_1 },
         { info: { id: 'data_2' }, data: data_2 },
       } 
    ]
   
  dispatch(addDataTopMap({ datasets, config: {} });

   }

  useEffect(() => {
 
   addData();

  },[data_2, data_1])

}
```